# Close system dialogs programmatically

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have a app that enters some IMM code and after code is entered the system pop's up dialog to inform what is happened(it's important). How can I close  system dialogs programmatically ? 
[image]

Below is my code :

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    Log.e("Focus debug", "Focus changed !");

    if (!hasFocus) {
        Log.e("Focus debug", "Lost focus !");
        Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
    }
}
```

And this code:(not work)

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));
```

And this code (Similar):(not work)

```
Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
    sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
```

After all this system dialogs still popup and wait until the user close it manualy

What can i do to make is work and close the system dialogs?

Comment: The above action will not close all system dialogs. . This is broadcast when a user action should request a temporary system dialog to dismiss. Some examples of temporary system dialogs are the notification window-shade and the recent tasks dialog.

Comment: So ? , You tell me that i can't close this dialog?
Or there is some force method to close it?
Even if i press "Ok" it will be fine

Comment: I do not think that this is possible because there are good arguments (do not do anything system critical without user interaction) against such an API.

Answer (score -1):

If you can hold a dialog instance with global Dialog instance, you can manually turn it off as you wish.

If that Dialog appears from your code, try something like this:

```
private Dialog mDialog;

public void whereDialogPopsup()
{
    AlertDialog.Buildder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder();
    ...
    mDialog = builder.show();
}

public void closeDialog()
{
    if(mDialog != null)
    {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        // remove it if you don't need any more
        mDialog = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes How can i do it?